# SVG feBlend in Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, svg, svg-filters

I would like to create a pattern by loading an image and then applying a multiply color filter on it.  However I think I am having trouble understanding the `in` and `in2` properties because it is not working.

What I am trying is to create the `<img>` and set `fill="green"` and then use `in="SourceGraphic" in2="FillPaint"`.  But I see an all white canvas in both firefox and chromium.  Anyone know why this isn't working?  Does blend work with `in*="FillPaint"`? I also tried just using separate rectangle and image and blending the two with `in2="BackgroundImage"` but that didn't work either.  Maybe because the "background" is not what I think it is when I'm inside the `pattern`?

Here's my code:

```
<filter id="multiply" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="FillPaint" mode="multiply"/>
</filter>

<pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32"  viewBox="0 0 
   32 32" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<image x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" fill="green" xlink:href=
  "dirt.png" filter="url(#multiply)"/>
</pattern>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
```

Comment: I just noticed that the feBlend example in the SVG documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/filters/feBlend.svg does not work in either browser...

Comment: That example works in Inkscape. Of course, if you're building them for use in browsers, that doesn't help.

Comment: Okay the problem seems to be with the implementation of feBlend.  I tried feColorMatrix (a diagonal matrix is the same as multiply) and it worked.  I don't know how it compares performance-wise, but I am only doing it on a small image which then gets tiled so I don't think it matters.

Comment: Jesse: Ah, thanks for confirming that is in fact an implementation error!

Answer (score 1):

Fillpaint as a filter input is not supported in most current browsers. That's why it's not working.